# Propagate an attached dependency property value to a template

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

Can an attached dependency property value be propagated to a templated children ?

Example : trying to propagate TagCloudService.* properties to the ItemTemplate

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl"
                pages:TagCloudService.MaximumFontSize="20"
                pages:TagCloudService.MaximumFontWeight="800"
                pages:TagCloudService.MinimumFontSize="10"
                pages:TagCloudService.MinimumFontWeight="400"
                pages:TagCloudService.NumberOfSizes="5"
                pages:TagCloudService.TagFrequency="{Binding Hotttnesss}"
                pages:TagCloudService.TagWeight="{Binding Weight}"
                Template="{StaticResource TagCloudItemsControlTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TermTagCloudTemplate" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is the item template where some default values have been defined but should be overridden :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TermTagCloudTemplate" DataType="api:Term">
        <TextBlock Foreground="DodgerBlue"
                    Padding="10"
                    Style="{StaticResource TagCloudTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    pages:TagCloudService.MaximumFontSize="30"
                    pages:TagCloudService.MaximumFontWeight="800"
                    pages:TagCloudService.MinimumFontSize="20"
                    pages:TagCloudService.MinimumFontWeight="400"
                    pages:TagCloudService.NumberOfSizes="5"
                    pages:TagCloudService.TagFrequency="{Binding Frequency}"
                    pages:TagCloudService.TagWeight="{Binding Weight}">
        </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've tried to set FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.OverridesInheritanceBehavior instead of .Inherits, tried to comment the default values in the template but the properties are not propagated.

Is this possible or should I just create another ItemTemplate for that control ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx

Comment: I've read it already.

Comment: Some genius out there found the solution !
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4249829/361899

Comment: Does the solution below fail to work?

Comment: Yes, value is not fetched from parent. Still another thing not right yet are the last two bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually easy.

Declare the attached property with `Inherits`-option:

```
public static string GetFoo(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (string)obj.GetValue(FooProperty);
}

public static void SetFoo(DependencyObject obj, string value)
{
    obj.SetValue(FooProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Foo", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
               "default",
               // this bit is important:
               FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

Test XAML:

```
<Grid src:MainWindow.Foo="non-default">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding (src:MainWindow.Foo),
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Grid>
```

shows "nondefault".

This works across template boundary as well, full example follows.

```
<Window x:Class="DPInheritance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:DPInheritance"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Test">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding (src:MainWindow.Foo),
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid src:MainWindow.Foo="non-default">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Test}">
            <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Unfortunately RelativeSource Self doesn't work, but FindAncestor does.

Comment: @Aybe: Strange, it runs successfully on my machine. Did you actually correct the attached property definition?

Comment: @Aybe: Well. Could you try my code example on your machine? (Here is the code-behind: http://pastebin.com/73iRhPJK)

Comment: I've just tried it, that's weird : it works only at runtime not on the designer which raises XamlParseException: Prefix 'src' does not map to a namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'll just stick to creating another template as I can't get the last two attached properties bindings from the ItemsControl, no idea on how to do it as these members cannot be resolved. I'll still mark yours as the answer because it is, in the mean time if you have any idea on how to bind these two from the ItemsControl, you're welcome.

Comment: @Aybe: Yes, I've got the same problem with the designer, but it's a designer's bug. About binding of the last 2 items: you are binding `pages:TagCloudService.TagFrequency` to `Hotttnesss` outside, and re-binding it to `Frequency` inside (overwriting the inherited value) -- what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Yes apparently a bug just as my attached properties are sometimes 'object not set to an instance of an object'. Sorry my code is a little misleading, on ItemsControl the binding to Frequency actually doesn't work but that's where ideally I'd like to bind the attached property TagFrequency to Frequency. That binding would override the default one defined in the DataTemplate. Right now the binding error is : 'cannot resolve symbol Hotttnesss due to unknown DataContext'

Comment: @Aybe: hm, and where is the binding error? In the `DataTemplate` or in the outer code (`ItemsControl`)?

Comment: In the ItemsControl, pages:TagCloudService.TagFrequency="{Binding Hotttnesss}" says 'cannot resolve symbol Hotttnesss due to unknown DataContext'.

Comment: @Aybe: Is the ItemsControl then a part of some outer DataTemplate? Otherwise I see no way to get this error.

Comment: No, the ItemsControl is actually what I'm putting on my Window.

Comment: Do you get the error at runtime or at compile time? If runtime, maybe you don't have the correct data context set? Or `Hotttnesss` is not a property but a field?

Comment: Hotttnesss is a property, I do get that warning on design-time and nothing happens at run-time. Regarding DataContext I absolutely have no have idea on what to put in but yes that's what VS hints. Actually I thought about replicating its behavior which sets a CollectionViewSource to DataContext, still need to try that.

Comment: @Aybe: well, you should have an object with property `Hotttnesss`, and this object must be assigned to your `Window`'s (or `UserControl`'s) `DataContext` property. (It may be even something like `this.DataContext = this;`)